# Gz giving unreadable data

Tags: php, sitemap, gzip

I am creating sitemap.xml using php. In which i have to create gz file which contains number of links.

Using following code.

```
$gzfile = $xmlfile.".gz";
$fp = gzopen ($gzfile, 'w9');
gzwrite ($fp, $photoxmldata);
gzclose($fp);
```

But when i open created gz file, it gives unreadable data.

Please help.

Comment: Use gunzip to unzip a copy of the file so you can read it.

Comment: i use that gzfile for google crawling. So internal xml file must be with plane. Its working on one server but not on another one.